Why is the vertical positioning of the font changing from one monitor to another?
The vertical position of my text is shifting from one screen to another (see screenshots).
The first screenshot is taken on my MacBook Pro 2021 (254ppi) and the other is taken on a Dell u3421we monitor (109ppi). As you can see, the whitespace above and below the text on the mac screen is balanced, but as soon as I move the screen over to the monitor, the whitespace becomes unbalanced.
MacBook

Dell Monitor
]2
I've tried playing around with baseline properties etc but to no avail! Am I missing something? What is causing this?

I've experienced the same issue while switching between operating systems (linix/windows). Also experienced this if I zoom in/out the screen using crtl +/-. My observation is someting weird with the font family. As not all font family behavies this way.

Could you expand more about the code that you have written? Possibily share the HTML and CSS. It could have something to do with monitor resolution, but with the informations you provided there's not much that can be understood.
Maybe some media queries?
